# Existence of a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p \in [1, + \infty)$ consider the Banach space $l^p=\{f=(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|^p<+\infty\}$. Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^2$ a sequence such that $a_n \neq0$ for every $n \geq1$. Show that exist a sequence $(b_n)_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(\frac{b_n}{a_n})_{n \geq 1} \notin l^2$. I try with the following:

I consider variuos cases:

1. If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^1$ then $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e $(\frac{b_n}{a_n})_{n \geq 1} \notin l^2$
2. If  $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \notin l^1$ we can take $(a_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where we have two subcases:

1.1 If  $(a_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^1$ then $(a_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, which implies that $(\frac{b_n}{a_n})_{n \geq 1}=(a_n)^\frac{1}{2} \notin l^2$

1.2 If  $(a_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \notin l^1$ we can take $(b_n)=(a_n)^{\frac{5}{2}}$ then $(\frac{b_n}{a_n})_{n \geq 1}=(a_n)^\frac{3}{2} \notin l^2$.

I don't know if my argument is correct, I don't know if I can continue in that way or are there other procedures to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $b_n=a_n$, we get $\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1 \not \in l^2$.